# How can I test concurrency of backend instance in development environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, concurrency, backend, load-testing

How can I test concurrency code of backend instance in development environment ? Here is my backends.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<backends>
    <backend name="hitsSaver">
        <class>B1</class>
        <instances>4</instances>
        <!-- max-concurrent-requests>20</max-concurrent-requests -->
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

In Development Console I see only one instance but "/_ah/start" was called 4 times. Are they all handled in the same thread ?

Comment: On the dev_appserver or in production? What are you trying to do?

Comment: On dev_appserver. I'm running the server under debugger and I'm load-testing it from 3 PCs using JMeter. Basically I just want to see ConcurrentModificationException thrown to check how it's handled in my code.

Comment: I don't think the dev_appserver will spawn multiple backend instances. With multithreading, though, you can have multiple concurrent requests, which should be sufficient. Testing with mocks and throwing that exception yourself would be a better idea. Bear in mind that if you're using datastore transactions, the transaction wrapper will catch that exception and retry.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. You should probably post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev_appserver will not spawn multiple backend instances. With multithreading, though, you can have multiple concurrent requests, which should be sufficient.

Testing with mocks and throwing that exception yourself would be a better idea. Bear in mind that if you're using datastore transactions, the transaction wrapper will catch that exception and retry.